# Node.js intermittent connection refused in development

Tags: node.js

When I run my node.js app in development I intermittently see connection refused an about every 2nd or 3rd request. I am not even sending the requests very quickly (about 1 per second). The requests should be completing very quickly as this is an express app with an end-point that is just checking if the content-type is set correctly. Is it likely that I am seeing the issue because I am not proxying the requests through nginx? Nginx would queue the requests; whereas not using nginx would mean that I am just hitting my node.js app directly. I don't see anything in my node.js app's logs that would indicate an error.

Comment: I am not sure what the original problem is. I did not change any code or restart my node app. The problem seems to have resolved its self. I recently upgraded to OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I don't know if that would have anything to do with the strangeness I saw. Perhaps there was something competing/conflicting for the port I was using for my node app.